# How i can upload image to the article?

Tags: php, laravel, image, upload

Please help me, I'm trying to figure out Laravel, it still doesn’t work out. I have created tables. Made a connection. Created Controllers. It seems to be correctly prescribed. I no longer understand how to do it so that in the form you can add a picture to this article and then display it. Help the dumb, please. I need my function  upload a picture for this article and then it can be displayed. Somehow you need to insert into the "create" function most likely. Please help.

CreateArticlesTable

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->text('description_short')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('meta_title')->nullable();
        $table->string('meta_description')->nullable();
        $table->string('meta_keyword')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('published')->nullable();
        $table->integer('viewed')->nullable();
        $table->integer('created_by')->nullable();
        $table->integer('modified_by')->nullable();


        $table->string('image_path'); //There image path
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

ArticleController.php

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $article = Article::create($request->all());

        if($request->input('categories'))  :
            $article->categories()->attach($request->input('categories'));
        endif;
        return redirect()->route('admin.article.index');    
    }
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.articles.index',[
            'articles' => Article::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10)
        ]);
    }

   public function create()
    {   
        return view('admin.articles.create',[
            'article' => null,
            'categories' => Category::with('children')->where('parent_id',0)->get(),
            'delimiter' => ''
        ]);
    }


 function upload(Request $request)
    {
     $this->validate($request, [
      'select_file'  => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,gif|max:2048'
     ]);

     $image = $request->file('select_file');

     $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

     $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);
     return back()->with('success', 'Image Uploaded Successfully')->with('path', $new_name);
    }
```

form.blade.php

```
 <label for="published">Status</label>
<select id="published" class="form-control" name="published">

@if (isset($article) && isset($article->id))
    <option value="0" {{ ($article->published == 0) ? 'selected' : '' }}>NO</option>
    <option value="1" {{ ($article->published == 1) ? 'selected' : '' }}>OK</option>
@else
    <option value="0" selected disabled>OK</option>
    <option value="1" disabled>NO</option>
@endif
</select>

<label for="title">Title</label>
<input id="title" type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="" value="{{ $article ? $article->title : '' }}" required>

<label for="slug">Slug </label>
<input id="slug" class="form-control" type="text" name="slug" placeholder="" value="{{ $article ? $article->slug : '' }}" readonly />

<label for="parent_id">Parent cat</label>
<select id="parent_id" class="form-control" name="categories[]" multiple="">
    @include('admin.categories.partials.categories', 
          ['categories' => $categories,
           'current' => $article,
           'delimiter' => $delimiter])

</select>
<label for="">Short desc</label>
<textarea name="description_short" class="form-control" id="description_short">{{$article->description_short or ""}}</textarea>

<label for="">Descr</label>
<textarea name="description" class="form-control" id="description_short">{{$article->description or ""}}</textarea>
<hr />


<label for="">Meta title</label>
<input  type="text" class="form-control" name="meta_title" placeholder="Meta title" value="{{ $article ? $article->meta_title : '' }}" required>

<label for="">Meta descrip</label>
<input  type="text" class="form-control" name="meta_description" placeholder="" value="{{ $article ? $article->meta_description : '' }}" required>

<label for="">Key</label>
<input  type="text" class="form-control" name="meta_keyword" placeholder="" value="{{ $article ? $article->meta_keyword : '' }}" required>


<div class="form-group">
 <table class="table">
  <tr>
   <td width="40%" align="right"><label>Select File for Upload</label></td>
   <td width="30"><input type="file" name="select_file" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td width="40%" align="right"></td>
   <td width="30"><span class="text-muted">jpg, png, gif</span></td>
   <td width="30%" align="left"></td>
  </tr>
```

create.blade.php

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app_admin')

@section('content')

<div class="container">

  @component('admin.components.breadcrumb')
    @slot('title') Create new  @endslot
    @slot('parent') Main @endslot
    @slot('active') News @endslot
  @endcomponent

  <hr />

  <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('admin.article.store')}}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    {{-- Form include --}}
    @include('admin.articles.partials.form')


  <input type="hidden" name="created_by" value="{{Auth::id()}}">
  </form>
</div>

@endsection
```

article.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('title', $article->meta_title)
@section('meta_keyword', $article->meta_keyword)
@section('meta_description', $article->meta_description)

@section('content')

<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h1>{{$article->title}}</h1>
                        <p>{!!$article->description!!}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
@endsection
```

filesystem.php

```
  'public' => [
             'driver' => 'local',
             'root'   => public_path() . '/uploads',
             'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
             'visibility' => 'public',
         ],
```

```
Route::get('/blog/article/{slug?}', 'BlogController@article')->name('article');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify that the form can post files via `enctype` attribute

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('admin.article.store')}}" 
method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And make use of the `upload` method in the controller

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $new_name = $this->upload($request);
    $article = Article::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'slug' => $request->slug,
        'description_short' => $request->description_short,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'meta_title' => $request->meta_title,
        'meta_description' => $request->meta_description,
        'meta_keyword' => $request->meta_keyword,
        'published' => $request->published,
        'viewed' => 0,
        'created_by' => auth()->id(),
        'modified_by' => auth()->id(),
        'image_path' => $new_name
    ]);
    if ($request->input('categories')) :
        $article->categories()->attach($request->input('categories'));
    endif;
    return redirect()->route('admin.article.index')->with('success', 'Image Uploaded Successfully')->with('path', $new_name);
}

function upload(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'select_file'  => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,gif|max:2048'
    ]);

    $image = $request->file('select_file');

    $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);
    return $new_name;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: also, it looks like the form is posting to "store" method but the controller has it as "upload"

Comment: Can't be sure, that's the route name, it could be pointing to an `upload` action method ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It’s necessary to somehow combine upload and store

Comment: We need to see your routes and the `store` method so we can tell

Comment: do you have two separate routes? one for "store" and one for "upload" because right now, your form is pointing to the store route but your controller has an "upload" method. I just want to check and make sure they are lined up the right way

Comment: I added the code Somehow I missed it for the first time. Please check my answer again

Comment: yeah your store method doesn't look like it's processing the file. you're not doing anything with moving the image path or anything. I would recommend combining the store and upload methods into one "store" method. Handle your file stuff in the "store". Also, @Saly3301 is right, you do need to change the enctype

Comment: @maximus1127 I wrote in the question that they need to be somehow connected, but I don’t understand how. It is necessary that he saves all the information from the form. And the file and everything else that I entered

Comment: I updated the question and connected the two methods, you can't have them both return a route redirect tho

Comment: And where should he save the picture?

Comment: Updated the answer* sorry, also the route you included is irrelevant, we need the route named `'admin.article.store'` pointing to `ArticleController` not `BlogController`

Comment: Everything works for me and so. I just need the picture to join this appendix.
``` Route::get('/blog/article/{slug?}', 'BlogController@article')->name('article'); ```
It's all right

Comment: I edited the code for slightly better security and a way to actually insert the image path in the table

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it solves the problem

Comment: Does not save and redirects to the same form page and that's it.  (((((((((((((((((

Comment: Thank you very much, it remains to withdraw

Comment: @Saly3301 the path does not save in the database

Comment: @NikitaKurilovic You need to put `image_path` to the `fillable` attribute in your model.

Comment: @nmfzone thanks. it saves just 2159.jpg. and I would need the fullest way

Comment: @NikitaKurilovic Is it still an issue?

Comment: @nmfzone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58778389/how-i-can-display-image-from-path-laravel