# How i can display image from path Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

there is my form.blade.php file

```
 D:\wamp\www\blog\resources\views\admin\articles\partials\form.blade.php
```

there is my images

```
D:\wamp\www\blog\public\images
```

How i can display it ?
I use this, but this not work for me.

```
<img src="../../../../public/images/ {{$article ? $article->image_path : ''}}" alt="">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<img src="{{URL::to('public/images').'/'.$article->image}}" alt="">
```

Comment: for me work this   ```<img src="{{URL::to('/images').'/'.$article->image_path}}" alt="">```
thanks

Answer (score 0):

`public` directory is publicly accessible. So, you can just set `src` as `/images/{{$article ? $article->image_path : ''}}`

Comment: for me work this <img src="{{URL::to('/images').'/'.$article->image_path}}" alt=""> thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
<img src="{{asset('public/images').'/'.$data->image}}" alt="">
```

Comment: for me work this <img src="{{URL::to('/images').'/'.$article->image_path}}" alt=""> thanks